# Android Mediarecorder setNextOutputFile IllegalStateException

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am trying to split my audio recording with android mediarecorder into multiple files, but whenever I set the next output file, I got an illegalstate exception.

Here's the code:

```
    private void getMediaRecorderReady(String filePath, FileDescriptor nextFile) {
    bufferSize = 88200;
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(100000);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.setNextOutputFile(nextFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's the error:

```
E/MediaRecorder: setNextOutputFile failed: -38
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.a49164.teachmi, PID: 31554
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                  at android.media.MediaRecorder._setNextOutputFile(Native Method)
                  at android.media.MediaRecorder.setNextOutputFile(MediaRecorder.java:878)
                  at com.example.a49164.teachmi.ExComThread.getMediaRecorderReady(ExComThread.java:189)
                  at com.example.a49164.teachmi.ExComThread.soundTransfer(ExComThread.java:211)
                  at com.example.a49164.teachmi.ExComThread.doInBackground(ExComThread.java:82)
                  at com.example.a49164.teachmi.ExComThread.doInBackground(ExComThread.java:46)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

So, after doing some digging, the error -38 equals to "-ENOSYS" or "INVALID_OPERATION", which seems to happen if the recorder is null or prepare hasn't been called (but I do call prepare() first).

Here's some native android code:

```
enum {
OK                = 0,    // Everything's swell.
NO_ERROR          = 0,    // No errors.

UNKNOWN_ERROR       = 0x80000000,
NO_MEMORY           = -ENOMEM,
INVALID_OPERATION   = -ENOSYS,
BAD_VALUE           = -EINVAL,
BAD_TYPE            = 0x80000001,
NAME_NOT_FOUND      = -ENOENT,
PERMISSION_DENIED   = -EPERM,
NO_INIT             = -ENODEV,
ALREADY_EXISTS      = -EEXIST,
DEAD_OBJECT         = -EPIPE,
FAILED_TRANSACTION  = 0x80000002,
JPARKS_BROKE_IT     = -EPIPE,
#if !defined(HAVE_MS_C_RUNTIME)
BAD_INDEX           = -EOVERFLOW,
NOT_ENOUGH_DATA     = -ENODATA,
WOULD_BLOCK         = -EWOULDBLOCK, 
TIMED_OUT           = -ETIMEDOUT,
UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION = -EBADMSG,
#else    
BAD_INDEX           = -E2BIG,
NOT_ENOUGH_DATA     = 0x80000003,
WOULD_BLOCK         = 0x80000004,
TIMED_OUT           = 0x80000005,
UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION = 0x80000006,
#endif    
FDS_NOT_ALLOWED     = 0x80000007,
};
```

Native nextoutputfile:

```
status_t MediaRecorder::setNextOutputFile(int fd)
{
ALOGV("setNextOutputFile(%d)", fd);
if (mMediaRecorder == NULL) {
    ALOGE("media recorder is not initialized yet");
    return INVALID_OPERATION;
}
// It appears that if an invalid file descriptor is passed through
// binder calls, the server-side of the inter-process function call
// is skipped. As a result, the check at the server-side to catch
// the invalid file descritpor never gets invoked. This is to workaround
// this issue by checking the file descriptor first before passing
// it through binder call.
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
if (flags == -1) {
    ALOGE("Fail to get File Status Flags err: %s", strerror(errno));
}
// fd must be in read-write mode or write-only mode.
if ((flags & (O_RDWR | O_WRONLY)) == 0) {
    ALOGE("File descriptor is not in read-write mode or write-only mode");
    return BAD_VALUE;
}
status_t ret = mMediaRecorder->setNextOutputFile(fd);
if (OK != ret) {
    ALOGE("setNextOutputFile failed: %d", ret);
}
return ret;
}
```

I may be wrong about the fact that -38 does equal -ENOSYS, but still, I have no idea why it's not working, since I'm passing a file descriptor and call it after prepare, as stated in the android documentation.

I really welcome your help, thanks !

EDIT: I tried to remove the setNextOutputFile(nextFile) right after prepare and only keep the one here:

```
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int infoCode, int extra) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------onMaxFileSizeApproaching " + infoCode);
            if (infoCode == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
                System.out.println("max sized reached");
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/dataSound" + currFile + ".aac";
                File nextFile = new File(path);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nextFile);
                    recorder.setNextOutputFile(fos.getFD());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String currPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/dataSound" + (currFile - 1) + ".aac";
                sendDataPath = currPath;
                currFile++;
            }
        }
    });
```

but to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

This mean that the `setNextOutputFile()` is called before `prepare()` [finish it's own work](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setNextOutputFile(java.io.File)).

So you should wait until your file prepared as discussed in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setNextOutputFile(java.io.File)).

The file is not used until switching to that output. Application will receive [`MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_NEXT_OUTPUT_FILE_STARTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_NEXT_OUTPUT_FILE_STARTED)

You should listen for the file info like:

```
recorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {
            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)
                recorder.setNextOutputFile(nextFile);
        }
    });
```

Also when the next output file is used. Application will not be able to set a new output file if the previous one has not been used. Application is responsible for cleaning up unused files after `stop()` is called.

Comment: So, I just tried to do as you recommend and I removed the setNextOutputFile() from right after prepare() and only kept the one inside the listener, but I still get the same error...

Comment: @Angelo well in that case it's better to listen for errors using `recorder.setOnErrorListener`

Comment: But listening to errors won't make "setNextOutputFile" works though, which is what I need :/

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, `setNextOutputFile` API must be called right after receiving on the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener a "what" code of MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING

```
mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this, "MediaRecorder onInfo:"+what, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.w("RecordActivity","MediaRecorder onInfo:"+what);
        if (what == MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING) {

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyRecordings");
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            Date date= new java.util.Date();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(date.getTime());
            String mediaFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4";
            File mediaFile = new File(mediaFilePath);

            Log.e("RecordActivity",mediaFilePath);
            try {
                RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(mediaFile, "rw");
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.setNextOutputFile(f.getFD());

                } finally {
                    f.close();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e("RecordActivity","",ex);
            }
        }
    }

});
```